# A question on the applicabiliy of minimax theorem

Tags: general-topology, optimization

Sion's minimax theorem is stated as:

> Let $X$ be a compact convex subset of a linear topological space and $Y$ a convex
>   subset of a linear topological space. Let $f$ be a real-valued function on $X \times Y$
>   such that 1. $f(x, \cdot)$ is
>    upper semicontinuous and quasi-concave on $Y$ for each $x \in X$.
>   2. $f( \cdot, y)$is lower semicontinuous and quasi-convex on $X$ for each $y \in Y$. Then: $$\inf_{x \in X}\sup_{y \in Y}f(x,y) = \sup_{y \in Y}\inf_{x \in X}f(x,y)$$

Suppose that the variable $x$ above is such a function,
$ \delta(\cdot): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow [0,1]$. My question is:

Does $X$ qualify as a compact convex subset of a linear topological space in this case? Assuming other conditions satisfied, does Sion's theorem hold, i.e.,

$$\inf_{\delta(z)}\sup_{y}f(\delta(z),y) \overset{?}= \sup_{y}\inf_{\delta(z)}f(\delta(z),y) $$

Pardon me if it is very trivial. I do not know anything about topological spaces.

Comment: For the part "lower semicontinuous and quasi-convex" you need $\delta^{-1}(0)$ to be a convex set.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is also a linear topological space. Let $X=\{\delta (z): z \in \mathbb R\}.$ If this $X$ is compact  convex (i.e. a closed bounded interval)  then your answer is "Yes."